# Not getting any emails from my Wordpress app on open shift

Tags: wordpress, openshift

I am not getting any emails (to the admins) from my Wordpress app on open shift. I installed it using the wordpress example.

I have a contact page form that was working in my other hosting provider.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue before where emails weren't sending and I added this to my functions.php file:

```
/**
* change WordPress default FROM email address
**/
add_filter('wp_mail_from', 'new_mail_from');
add_filter('wp_mail_from_name', 'new_mail_from_name');
function new_mail_from($old) {
$email = get_option( 'admin_email' );
return $email;
}
function new_mail_from_name($old) {
$site_name = get_option( 'blogname');
return $site_name;
}
```

Comment: cool will try, also wonder if openshift mail is being stopped by google cause its from Amazon EC

Comment: why is the from mail important in your case?

Answer (score -1):

I would erase all of that. I am a very good user in this situation.

#1 every time you change the server, you have to redo the mailer settings.
#2 only and I do mean only use wp-mailer plugin.
#3 set your settings correctly and follow the instructions if you are using wordfence.
#4 for woo, you have to style the mailer in ftp.